# Which building is this? And where is it located?

Tags: identify-this, north-america

[image: where is this]

This is a picture of the skyline that is printed in the elevator of my building. It's killing me that I don't know where it is. Can anyone help me?

There are three elevators in the building, one is New York, the other one is Las Vegas so it seems likely this one would be in North America as well.

Comment: Posting a picture of the whole image instead of just that building may help, I tried to reverse search it on a few different things and it won't pick up the fact that it is a building

Comment: Have you tried leaving a note attached to the image in the elevator asking fellow passengers if they have the answer? could be fun...

Comment: @Daanvanwouw can you post a picture of the whole image?

Comment: Put on hold until we can get more info from OP